# Filter on "include" - Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails

these are my associations:

```
class Activity < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :infos, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :events, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :infos

end

class Event < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :activity
  has_many :infos, :through => :activity

end

class Info < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_one :language
  belongs_to :activity

end
```

Now i can get an XML with all the events and their infos using:

@events = Event.all

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.xml  { render :xml => @events.to_xml(:include => [:infos ]) }
end
```

The problem is that i get the infos from all the language.

**Is it possible to use a filter (as "where info.language.id==1"), so that only the language1 infos are displayed in the XML for each event?**

Thanks

**UPDATE :**

Hi Mike, thanks for your answer.

Unfortunately i'm getting this error:

> undefined method `eq' for nil:NilClass
>   Rails.root: /Users/abramo/village
>
> Application Trace | Framework Trace |
>   Full Trace
>   app/controllers/events_controller.rb:29:in
>   `block (2 levels) in locale'
>   app/controllers/events_controller.rb:28:in`
>   locale'

and lines 28,29 are the last line of my locale method:

```
  def locale
    @events = Event.joins(:infos => :language).where("languages.id = 2")

    respond_to do |format|
      format.xml  { render :xml => @events.to_xml(:include => [:infos ]) }
    end
  end
```

I really don't understand... what object is Nil?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Event.joins(:infos => :language).where("languages.id = 1")
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the problem is still here! (have a look at my updated post)